# Getting URLs from FB Group Page

Tags: python, ajax, facebook

I'm completely lost how to get URLs of Facebook profiles from a Facebook group. After clicking the "See All" button and inspecting a link to person's profile in the developer console, I'm able to view the link to their profile. If I scroll down to the bottom of the pop-up, then I can view all of the links in the developer console.  But if I go to 'view source' then I cannot access those links. Any advice on how to get all the links to people's profiles?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the context of your problem. Are you using one of Facebook's API's? The question gives the impression that your trying to scrape this information out of the browser.

Comment: I'm trying to scrape out of the browser.

Comment: Actually just realized that I can get everything by c/p from developer console in Firefox.

Comment: Cool, if you're interested in how to do this task through a facebook API check out facebook's API explorer tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer